# In Vue3, Is it possible component slot's input pass to child slot in Render?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, render

I have a component named 'ABC'

```
<template>
    <div>
        Some text
        <slot/>
    </div>
    <slot name="header"></slot> 
</template>
```

And for some reason(defineCustomElement)
I use 'ABC' component with render and create outer Component.
This component named 'OUTER'

```
import ABC from './ABC.vue'
setup(props, context) {
    ....
    return () => h(ABC , ...props);
}
```

And I use 'OUTER' component this way

```
<OUTER>
    <div>Hello</div>
    <template #header>Bye</template>
</OUTER>
```

But I can't render slot's content.
How I can pass slot to child component?

#### Additional Inforamtion

I want to use ABC Component as a web component.
And I found vue support web component with 'defineCustomElement'
But I need install other plugins to web component.
So I found the way, wrapping this component
This is 'OUTER' component's full code

```
import ABC from './ABC.vue';
import plugins from './plugins.js
const OUTER = defineCustomElement({
    styles: style,
    props: ABC.props,
    emits: ABC.emits,
    template: {},
    setup(props, context) {
        const app = createApp();
        app.use(plugins);
        const inst = getCurrentInstance();
        Object.assign(inst.appContext, app._context);
        Object.assign(inst.provides, app._context.provides);
        return () => h(ABC , ...props);
    }
}
customElements.define('OUTER', OUTER);
```

I expect 'ABC' Component get

Hello
Bye

But 'ABC' Component can't get any slot input

Answer (score 0):

Passing slots to your ABC component can be done like this:

```js
setup(props, { slots }) {
  return () => h(ABC, { ...props }, { ...slots })
}
```

[Vue Playground demo](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)